# Kendo UI Grid saveRow method doesn`t sync data and doesn`t close the row

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

Here is the [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Casufi/zK489/18/) to test.
I am trying to setup grid with the in-line editing. Why saveRow method doesn`t affect update function in transport definition and doesn`t exit row from edit mode ?

Also please try to change var "can_edit" to false; Why this option doesn`t affect the field "day1"

Answer (score 0):

If you debug your code for detecting the pressed key:

```
dataBound: function (o) {
    ...
    o.sender.element.delegate('tbody>tr', 'keypress', function (e, o) {
        if (!e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey && e.key == "Enter") {
            if ($(".k-grid-edit-row").length > 0) {
                grid.saveRow();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You will see that you never get to `grid.saveRow()`. Try using `e.keyCode` instead:

```
if (!e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your code did not change anything. Please check an update fiddle